# PULP Minimize costs and deviations/errors constraints

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I have an LP in python that includes the following code:

Objective Function:

```
model = LpProblem("OneProductCost",LpMinimize)
model += lpSum([y[i] + abs(delta) for i in range(N)]), "Objective function"
```

Constraint:

```
 for i in range(p):
    model += lpSum([z[i,j] for j in range(N)]) == Pallet*y[j] - delta, "Empty space constraints %s" %j
```

I define delta as a float within the function but for whatever reason it is not registered. Is there anyone who has successfully implemented goal programming to PULP like this? This is only a sample of the total LP.

Comment: `abs` is not allowed in an LP. Most LP textbooks explain how to reformulate this.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Ok, the abs notwithstanding, could you help me formulate the delta constraints? I just want to minimize the deviation/error

Comment: That constraint looks rather messed up to me. `y[j]` should probably read `y[i]`, `delta` should probably be `delta[i]`. I would suggest to first write down a proper mathematical model and then transcribe it into Pulp/Python syntax.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen ok thank you! is there any specific online resource that addresses this? I have not been able to find anything very helpful

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen that's not very specific...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177956/discussion-between-tobeybryant-and-erwin-kalvelagen).